# Autofill in chrome using Autofill Service Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-autofill-manager

In Pie & Above versions, Android introduced the chrome browser autofill using the Autofill service as per the doc.

But i tried debug the Facebook's login form in Chrome Browser for the onFillRequest call to come. But it's not coming. Don't know anything else i need to add in code or permissions.

But in apps like Facebook, i am getting onFillRequest call is coming. For browsers only it has problem.

Device Name: Pixel 3

I have checked in Dashlane also.

Dashlane Scnario:

I have seen a news that Dashlane integrated the Autofill for chrome using Autofill Service. I have installed the app and tried it. It still uses accessibility service to fill the form. I have latest chrome browser and dashlane app.

Could you please help me top find an issue for browser's autofill using Autofill Service.

Comment: This would interest me as well. Chrome on a physical device makes problems, it works in the emulator and even in Firefox on the device. Have you figured out anything?

Comment: No, I didn't figured out. If anything from your side, Please let me know as well. I will also let you know once i figured out.

Comment: Anybody make any ground here? Looks like Chrome is taking precedence over the selected autofill service on mobile @Vji

Comment: Related bug reports: https://github.com/bitwarden/mobile/issues/489 , https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=849774#c_ts1599854560 , https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1015381 , https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1103555 , https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1103560

Comment: I am also trying to get a handle on this, is the inputIME a solution?